# installi ubuntu 18.04 on acer aspire s7-391

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, raid

i'm trying to install ubuntu 18.04 64bit version on an acer s7-391, it is an ultrabook with a 128GB ssd hdd in raid 0.

After the installation, i receive the message no bootable device found.
Here what i did, with no luck after googling

1. hdd is in first position on bootable devices
2. tried to install with legacy bios
3. tried to set UEFI from  trustable resource but where the hdd0 supposed to 
   be,it's empty

I can't change the raid 0 to IDE from bios.
It has appeared an unkwnow devices in the boot list
I've read that the problem could be solved making a new partition table, but i really don't know how to do that.
Thanks

Comment: Changing RAID 0 to anything else will totally break system. Half you data is on one drive and half on other, With hard drives it was alternating tracks. And you would not want IDE as that is for 10 year old systems with old drives. Generally AHCI is preferred, but unless you want to totally back up Windows and reinstall in standard mode it cannot be used. If Windows is UEFI, you still want Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This user totally reinstalled: https://askubuntu.com/questions/590644/install-ubuntu-14-04-2-lts-alongside-windows-8-1-dual-boot-on-raid-acer-s7-quest

Comment: @oldfred *Generally AHCI is preferred*, of course, except in very rare cases like the one with my friend's new(ish) i7 laptop: https://superuser.com/questions/1346582/very-slow-sshd-in-ahci-mode-affecting-windows-only

Comment: @Daitam If you just installed - and don't mind doing it again - you can try different modes. I would change it to AHCI.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I delete totally windows10 partition because the upgrade to windows creator edition was always stuck. I'll give a try to set AHCI mode and following oldfred links. I'll keep you posted

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS, is then how it installs for both Windows & Ubuntu. Generally with newer systems UEFI is better. But either way both systems need to be in same boot mode. Windows wants multiple partitions with UEFI and has to have gpt partitioning for UEFI boot.

Comment: I've managed to successfully install ubuntu using AHCI, but now the OS only see a 64GB hdd. How can I extend it to the remaining 64GB?

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be faced for wrong partitioning when you setting up OS..
Make sure that your partition table is correct...
Please use MBR partition for fix this problem...
**Linux installetion partition required:**

1. /boot EXT4 (200/300MB)
2. / EXT4(For root partition minimum 20GB)
3. Swap area (3/4GB)

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFOmc.png)

Ive installed linux(Ubuntu and kali) by making this partition table in my legacy bios..
Please Try it. It may fix your problem.
-Thank you
(I'm new here. Sorry for any kind of mistake)